# Считывать текст с формы на c#

Tags: c#, list, textbox, online

Не могу разобраться как считывать каждое слово с textbox в listbox. Нужно чтоб когда введено какое-то слово в textbox вводилось в listbox сразу же.

Comment: Пока видна констатация факта "не могу разобраться", но не видно предпринятых усилий.

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "вводилось" - нажатие на Enter, пробел и т.д. И уточните что вы используете `WinForms` или `WPF`?

Answer (score 3):

Если я правильно понял вопрос и Ваше приложение принадлежит типу "Windows Forms", то данную задачу можно решить с помощью метода Split(), класса String.

Вам требуется сделать событие KeyPress для элемента TextBox, в обработке которого требуется поместить проверку на нажатие пробела. При срабатывания этого события Вы преобразуете Вашу строку в массив, критерием разделения элементов в массиве будет являться пробел (который задается в параметрах метода Split()).

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) // событие KeyPress Вашего TextBox
    {
        if (e.KeyChar == (char) Keys.Space)  // Проверяете нажатую клавишу, если это пробел - выполняется код в теле if
        {
            listBox1.Items.Clear();  //очищаете элементы Вашего ListBox
            AddToList(); // И добавляется туда все введенные слова с Вашего TextBox.
        }
    }
```

И далее Вам будет необходимо при каждом новом нажатии пробела (реализация данного метода может меняться, в зависимости от Ваших потребностей, это лишь один из примеров) чистить Ваш ListBox и заносить туда все написанные через пробел слова.

```
    private void AddToList()
    {
        var wordsArray = textBox1.Text.Split(' '); // Критерий для разбиения Вашей строки в массиве.
        foreach (var word in wordsArray)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(word);
        }
    }
```